# How to launch .sh from third party program?

Tags: command-line, scripts, games, sh

I have the program Lutris installed on my computer and I am going through adding all my linux games. However some are .sh execs others are .bins and executables which both added fine. the .sh ones are giving me some grief. [image: issue]

I don't know what to put in the argument section to help launch the game. It's an easy fix I know it is. I just can't think of it, a little brain dead here :P

-EDIT-

I just threw sudo sh in there as something to see if it worked but it didn't.

Example:

The games that are in .sh launch straight from the shell script file there are no install screens or anything I just run the terminal command and the game is open, Lutris just simplifies that by adding them all together in a manager so I don't have to type as much :P

So if I don't need an argument that is for after the program is launch do I need a preload library?  As Lutris sees the file (I think) its supposed to be an executable that I just double click on the icon and the game starts.

I can simplify this cause I know I am sometimes a little confusing with my words.

Lutris is a launcher for linux games and gaming on ubuntu in general. The games I have are .sh format, They aren't installers  but launchers. I can go into terminal and type the sh commands and run the game fine, I am just trying to add said games to Lutris and I guess Lutris doesn't see it as an Executable even though I have it checked under permissions in the GUI

Comment: That will depend on what `dontstarve.sh` actually does. Why are you launching it with `sudo`? Is that necessary? In any case, `sudo sh` is not an argument, arguments are what come _after_ the program, for example `sh` is an argument to `sudo` here. If you need to run `dontstarve.sh` as root, you'll need to make a wrapper script that calls it with `sudo` and give the wrapper to Lutris instead. Please [edit] your question and clarify the situation, I'd be happy to write the little wrapper for you.

Comment: hopefully that helps understand better.

Answer (score 0):

#### Running bash files

To run an **.sh** (bash) file, you have two options

1. Force run with `bash`

   - `$ bash /path/to/file.sh`
2. Allow execution

   - `$ chmod +x /path/to/file.sh`
   - `$ ./path/to/file.sh`

Typically, files downloaded from the internet are **not** marked as executable (+x) until you specifically mark them so.

#### Creating "Shortcuts"

You may want to create a "Shortcut" or clickable icon that launches your games

- `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new`

To ensure that the file runs, use the `bash /path/to/file.sh` method when inputting the command.